# Could we get a macro to convert units (°C <-> °F)?

Tags: feature-request

On https://cooking.stackexchange.com, but also on other pages we need units for the temperature or lengths.

Unfortunately it is still not common to use SI units in US. In order to make the answers more readable for everyone in the world, I suggest to add a macro, which can display both.
SI units and in parenthesis the non SI unit

**Examples how units could be rendered by the macro**

100 °C (212 °F)

24 mm (1 in)

Comment: Would _“100 °C (212 °F)”_ (e.g. in your post) then be converted to _“100 °C (212 °F) (212 °F)”_ or even _“100 °C (212 °F) (212 °F (100 °C))”_?

Comment: Wikipedia has the [`convert`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Convert) "template". Example: `{{convert|34.96|oz|kg|disp=flip|sigfig=2|abbr=on}}` - output "0.99 kg (35 oz)"

Comment: There is no Kelvin converter on physics.se :D ?

Comment: I understand the frustration, but I don't think automatically inserting more units is the answer. This will probably break a lot of already existing posts.

Comment: Perhaps changing policy of the relevant sites is a better idea (assuming there is indeed a big problem). Or sharing a converter that helps out (many search engines incl. Google and DDG have one built-in for most units).

Comment: For many browsers there are addons that will convert values and units on the fly into whichever system you prefer.

Comment: The cooking site could probably benefit from adding conversion to and from [henweighs](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=henweigh) also.

Comment: We could also add a converter on the website and demand SI units by policy. But I guess the acceptance would be higher with a macro.

Comment: @SebastianSimon 100 °C (212 °F) should be the finally printed format.

Comment: @JonasStein The point of my comment was to hint at the difficulty of parsing the text and recognizing if the converted unit is already included. There are more difficulties, e.g. using `℃` instead of `°C`, or just `C` or `centigrade`. What about Kelvin; or if someone uses `K` instead of `K`?

Comment: If we do this, we absolutely need the capability to convert velocity to Fulongs per Fortnight.

Comment: I tend to edit questions on WB when I see only imperial units (and occasionally if I see only metric units). But when I do that, I round the conversion to something that sounds more natural unless exact measurements are needed. They rarely are - if somebody says they want a 100 yard tall robot or something, I'd convert that to 90m instead of 91.44m because the length is used as a guidance. Conversely 100m are 109.361 yards but I'd round to 110 yards. Point being that automatic translation would use very precise and useless numbers and in many cases.

Answer (score 15):

> it is still not common to use SI units in US

Right.

Let's not slow down the process of adapting the metric units. If there are less and less places where they get their units conveniently converted there is no other option then to fit in.

Besides Google is one click away, to convert units.

Implementing this is not trivial, for little gain.

I don't think this is a valuable addition today and even if it does make it on the roadmap I prefer it to be very low priority.

Comment: As an American, I can confirm that measuring devices that use SI units are readily available here.

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget that nearly every single measurement has regional variations. Australian, US and British cups come to mind.

For that matter *volumetric* measures of two fairly common US brands of salt.... [result in different things](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/how_to_swap_morton_kosher_salt_for_diamond_crystal_and_vice_versa/).

As such, it might be useful to ask users to clarify what they mean.

Comment: There was a long running thread (on Twitter IIRC) regarding grand mum handed down recipes and number of cups required. It turned out that many of those recipes required the specific cup used by grand mum and nobody recalls **which** cup it was ...

Comment: Or it was literally a specific random non standard cup 